# pass parameter to script create trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function with parameter and would like to script create trigger for unattended function execution.

```js
function getLastNdays(nDaysAgo) {
  var today = new Date();
  var before = new Date();
  before.setDate(today.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
  return Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

function runNextTrigger() {
  
    var GUID = "!Q@W#E$RI"
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var nextTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("getLastNdays").timeBased().after(1 * 60 * 1000).create();
    
    var triggerId = nextTrigger.getUniqueId();
    userProperties.setProperty("LastNdays_" + GUID, triggerId);    
}
```

Even though the trigger is created it does nothing as no parameter value is being passed is there a way to pass parameter to the script create trigger.

Comment: I haven't tried this but you could try adding/using spreadsheet to track the `nDays` ago (for date comparison). Use the data from the spreadsheet to get the value and then use [installed triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run your unattended function.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you something like that

```
function getLastNdays(before) {
if(!(before instanceof Date)){
  var timestamp = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("LastNdays_" +before.triggerUid);
  before = new Date();
  before.setTime(timestamp);
}

  //var today = new Date();
  //var before = new Date();
  //before.setDate(today.getDate() - nDaysAgo);
 return Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd'); // notice return wont return anywhere as it's the function called
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("SSID")
 .getSheetByName("Sheet2").appendRow([new Date(), Utilities.formatDate(before, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd')]); // used a spreadsheet to log the action
 }

function runNextTrigger() {

    var GUID = "!Q@W#E$RI"
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var nextTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("getLastNdays").timeBased().after(10).create();

    var triggerId = nextTrigger.getUniqueId();
    //userProperties.setProperty("LastNdays_" + GUID, triggerId);
    var now = new Date();
    userProperties.setProperty("LastNdays_" + triggerId,now.getTime());
}
```